# definition of accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

is correct the following definition?

-- "let $ s \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ T \subseteq \mathbb{R} $, $ s $ is accumulation point for $ T $ if $ \forall S \in \mathcal{U}(s)((S-\{s\})\cap T \neq \emptyset ) $"

thanks in advance!!

P.S.= $\mathcal{U}(s):=\{S| S \mbox{ is neighbourhood of } s\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accumulation point $s$, of the set $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ or limit point $s$, of $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ are those points of $\mathbb{R}$ whose any nbd contains a point of $T$ other than $s$.

Thus for any nbd $S \in U(s)$ of $s$ if we shall delete $s$, then intersection of the deleted nbd $S-\{s\}$ with $T$ will be non empty.

So your expression $$(S -\{s\})\cap T \neq \phi$$ is correct.